# How to SetFormula() to Cell in row hidden by filter applied in google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can anyone help with this , I found that google script can SetValue to hidden filtered rows but SetFormula doesn't work , the output is blank cell:
I have sheet applied filter from A1 to A999 , the only showed rows as per certain condition are ROWS 1 to 4 as the screenshot, row 10 is unfiltered and hidden ,  if I run the below code, nothing resulted in cell C10....

[sheet filtered-showed rows from 1 to 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFZgk.png)
/////

[code run - and removed filter to check if C10 received function or not - found blank without any formula set to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWO77.png)

if I removed the filter , and run the code ...C10 receive the function please refer to screenshot

[without filtering - and C10 is showing on sheet - run the code received the formula in C10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOxtA.png)

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1') ; 

var formula=sheet.getRange('C10').setFormula('=iferror(Vlookup($A5863,TRANSACTIONS_QUEUE!$B:$E,3,0),"")');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can temporarily remove the filter and set it back after setting the formula

Sample:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1') ; 
  var filter = sheet.getFilter();
  var filterColumn = 1;
  var criteria =  filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(filterColumn);
  filter.removeColumnFilterCriteria(filterColumn);
  var formula=sheet.getRange('C10').setFormula('=iferror(Vlookup($A5863,TRANSACTIONS_QUEUE!$B:$E,3,0),"")');
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(filterColumn, criteria)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All concerned can also star the issue on Google Issue Tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38098262